# VBA merging different sheets doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to consolidate several sheets by copying data starting from A40 in each sheet
and pasting in a new worksheet

The code doesn't result in error but nothing is copied

Could you help please

Thanks

```
Sub merge_cognos()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim startRow As Long
Dim startcol As Integer

Dim lastCol As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws_new = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> ws_new.Name Then
        startRow = 40
        startcol = 1
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, startcol).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = Cells(startRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
        'get data from each worksheet and copy it into Master sheet
        Range(Cells(startcol, startRow), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy
        ws_new.Paste
    End If
Next ws

ws_new.Select
With Selection
.Range("F1", Range("F1").End(xlDown)).Sort Key1:=Range("F1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
.Columns("F:F").Select
   Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
   Selection.EntireRow.Delete
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome Mlamb! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: If you write `Range` or `Cells`, VBA will assume that you want to work with the Activesheet (which is the sheet that you just created). If you want to access a different sheet, you need to tell that to VBA: `lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, startcol).End(xlUp).Row`. Or use a `With`-statement to qualify the sheet, in that case your line could look like `lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, startcol).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: I try to do as you said but it still doesn't work ;/

I wrote ws.lastrow and ws.lastcol but nothig is copied I think the issue is either from the starting cell or from the copy pasting method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I revised your code in order to:

- avoid use of Select/Selection
- reference the proper worksheet at every stage

as follows:

```
Sub merge_cognos()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim startcol As Integer
    
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Dim ws_new As Worksheet
        Set ws_new = wb.Sheets.Add
    
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            With ws
                If .Name <> ws_new.Name Then
                    startRow = 40
                    startcol = 1
                    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, startcol).End(xlUp).Row
                    lastCol = .Cells(startRow, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    'get data from each worksheet and copy it into Master sheet
                    .Range(.Cells(startRow, startcol), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy
                    With ws_new
                        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
                    End With
                End If
            End With
        Next
        
        With ws_new
            .Range("F1", .Range("F1").End(xlDown)).Sort Key1:=.Range("F1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
            .Columns("F:F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! Sadly it still doesn't do anything :/

Comment: too broad an information. you have to step through the code line by line by pressing F8 and watch what happens

Comment: Alright ! It tells me that the pastespecial method failed

Comment: are you using the very same code as per my answer?

Comment: yes ! it either tell me this or it odesn't copy paste anything

Comment: when you reach the "With ws_new" code line, switch to Excel and see if in the current ws (you get its name typing ?ws.Name in Immediate Window and pressing return) there's a range highlighted (which would mean it is being copied)

Comment: no there is no range highlighted !

Comment: Sorry I hadn't posted the last revision of the code. See edited answer where I moved the "With ws_new  /  .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial  /   End With" code section inside the "If .Name <> ws_new.Name Then  .. End If" clause

Comment: it leads to the same result sadly :/

Comment: please tell me what happens when stepping through the code and what's wrong exactly

Comment: I found the answer, in the .rangecopy i misplaced the startrow and startcol. So it didn't select well my first cell !

Comment: good to know
If my answer solves your question, you might then consider marking it as accepted. Thank you

Comment: @Mlamb, please take care to properly handle your question by marking the proper answer as the solution. Thanks